# is_user_logged_in is not working outside of wordpress directory

Tags: php, wordpress

I just can't seem to get is_user_logged_in working outside of my wordpress directory.

I have wordpress installed in mydomain/news/

If I execute for example mydomain/test.htm and have within the html an iframe where the source is within mydomain/news then the following code in that iframe works:

```
<?php
session_start();
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false ); 
Include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/news/wp-load.php');
if ( is_user_logged_in() )
{
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$username=$current_user->user_login;
}
?>
```

But I need to execute the test from within the mydomain/test.htm and not from within an iframe that is within mydomain/news

When I try the following code directly in mydomain/test.htm it does not return the $username - is_user_logged_in() returns false.

```
<?php
session_start();
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false ); 
Include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/news/wp-load.php');
if ( is_user_logged_in() )
{
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$username=$current_user->user_login;
}
?>
```

Has anyone any idea why I am not getting is_user_logged_in() to return true? - I am definitely logged in when executing the test code.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Struggling with the same issue.

Comment: Well yes and no.
I have wordpress in a sub-directory of my root directory. So for a php module in my root directory needing to check if a user is logged in, I ended up placing code into my wordpress directory that I included into my root directory php module as an iframe. 
It was a bit of a hack but works. I still have no idea though why the code will not work from outside the wordpress directory.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned: `mydomain/test.htm`, therefore unless your server is setup to execute `.htm` through PHP then it'll not work, you'll need to change the file format to `.php`.

Comment: The server is set up to execute .htm through php I use php extensively on htm pages

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I found was to add the following code to wp-config.php:

```
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/wp/wp-admin');
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '');
define('COOKIEPATH', '');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');
```

Note that this code shall be added in the middle of wp-config.php, i.e. before the line: `/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */`. And you shall replace "/wp/wp-admin" depending on where your wordpress installation is located (in this example the main path is at /wp, and there is a subfolder /wp/wp-admin).